# mitmproxy headers stripped with tls_passthrough script?

Tags: linux, proxy, system-administration, mitmproxy

```
mitmdump -p 8080 --rawtcp --modify-headers :~q:User-Agent:@~/useragent.txt -s tls_passthrough.py
```

Using the above command (with and without --rawtcp) causes the header modification to not work. Remove the tls_passthrough script and the headers are modified just fine. Is there a workaround for this? Not entirely sure how to handle this by using the following:

```
--certs *=ca.pem
```

Do I generate this with the OpenSSL or pull it from ~/.local/mitmproxy?

Seeking guidance please.

Comment: If you pass through TLS connections they are not decrypted by Mitmproxy hence they can't be modified.

Comment: Thank you Robert. I'll follow-up question on how to work this out on the Slack or IRC. Thanks again Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this can't be done, once the connection over TLS has been made the catch is that you can't "look into it" as otherwise it would be pretty much insecure.

What you can do instead is be a man in the middle that also has a TLS connection to the client

```
client <- TLS -> MITM <- TLS -> server
```

Then the client will encrypt everything with a key that you know and you can do the same with the server.

It might not work though

1. the client has to accept you certificate
2. the client might check that the certificate you expose is the one he knows already (a previous connection, hardcoded id, etc)

if you have a valid certificate and the client accept this and it does connect with your proxy then you can change the headers using the MITM technique.

If you look at the source for the [tls_passthrough script you mention](https://github.com/sociam/x-ray/blob/master/mitmproxy/examples/tls_passthrough.py) you can see
a short description of what it will do based on the HTTP/HTTPS combinations you can run.

```
    > mitmdump -s tls_passthrough.py
    1. curl --proxy http://localhost:8080 https://example.com --insecure
    // works - we'll also see the contents in mitmproxy
    2. curl --proxy http://localhost:8080 https://example.com --insecure
    // still works - we'll also see the contents in mitmproxy
    3. curl --proxy http://localhost:8080 https://example.com
    // fails with a certificate error, which we will also see in mitmproxy
    4. curl --proxy http://localhost:8080 https://example.com
    // works again, but mitmproxy does not intercept and we do *not* see the contents
```

In this example `curl` is the client making the request and you can see that sometimes it has to be called with `--insecure` to allow the connection to go through a *insecure* proxy.

Comment: For anybody needing the more recent version of `tls_passthrough.py` go to https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/contrib/tls_passthrough.py.

Comment: @JariTurkia you absolute legend! thank you! I have been scouring the internet for the latest update of that script for months now.